# Django rest framework multiple endpoints for one page at frontend

Tags: django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework, endpoint

First time im building api's for SPA. And now i wonder how to do some of them right.
For example, we all have delivery club app and main page of a restaurant has banners, some info about, categories, products. Product detail pop up has info about product, measure units, modifiers, additivies and some more options.
So i understand how to build api's for admins dashboard but how to do it for clients app?
They should be all seperated and front-end will get them all together or my serializers should be nested? Can someone tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every view you want, you return the appropriate data and of course load your front-end with the data gotten.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is tricky thing for me here.  So frontend can merge all endpoints together on a one page?

Comment: I'm sure you have different endpoints for different functionality. So, yes you can call different endpoint in one page since it's a SPA.